# How can i find the days, hours and minutes difference between two columns in a calculated column

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, calculated-column-formula

I want to create the functionality of this formula which works in excel `=Text([end date]-[start date],"d:h:mm")` in a sharepoint calculated column. It works with h:mm, but when I include the d or D I get unexpected results.

Comment: After more consideration the 'd' doesn't do what I was intending. When the dates differ by several months it gives unexpected results.

Comment: What would you want to see when the difference is several months?

Comment: I want the result as number of days : number of leftover hours : number of leftover minutes

Comment: See my latest edit.

Comment: THANK YOU!! that works perfect Teylyn. 

If only date time columns would use one minute increments I would be completely happy.

Comment: You can change the form and manipulate the date/time controls. Details here: http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.co.nz/2011/06/sharepoint-edit-date-and-time-in-one.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot connect the "d" with a colon to the time value. The colon can only be used to separate hours, minutes and seconds. Use a blank instead of the colon

```
=Text([end date]-[start date],"d h:mm")
```

[image]

Edit: If the days go over one month, then the following approach may be better:

```
=IF(End-Start>1,INT(End-Start)&":","")&TEXT(End-Start,"h:mm")
```

[image]

Days will only show if present and can run into the tens of thousands. Note: My regional settings are DMY.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try formats in this post to see if you get the result you want http://panvega.wordpress.com/2008/12/08/ddwrtformatdate-with-different-formatflags/

Saw another example this might work too

```
Text([end date]-[start date],"d") &":"& Text([end date]-[start date],"h:mm")
```

Comment: Thanks Teylyn, couldn't up vote your answer or attach my comment, too new on this forum :)

Answer (score -1):

CONCATENATE(ROUNDDOWN([end date]-[start date],0),":",TEXT([end date]-[start date],"hh:MM")